# Tree data structure with multiple keys for each item

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I'm working on a chat application using **node js** that displays a list of online users. Each user has the following attributes:

**ipv4, rank, score, login time**

**ipv4** is used when accessing a user.

Users should be listed according to this sorting strategy:

- **Users with higher rank should be at the top of the list.**
- **If the user rank is equal, the users with the highest score should be at the top of the list after high-rank users.**
- **If the user score is equal, users with less login time should be at the top of the list after high-score users.**

for example:

**1**. Login **userA (ipv4:1.1.1.1, rank:0, score:3000, loginTime:1631966424070)**

- list: **[userA]**

**2**. Login **userB (ipv4:2.2.2.2, rank:1, score:2000, loginTime:1631966424080)**

- list: **[userB, userA]**

**3**. Login **userC (ipv4:3.3.3.3, rank:1, score:1000, loginTime:1631966424090)**

- list: **[userB, userC, userA]**

**4**. Login **userD (ipv4:4.4.4.4, rank:0, score:3000, loginTime:1631966424100)**

- list: **[userB, userC, userA, userD]**

**Access example:**

Get **user(ipv4:3.3.3.3)** -> return **userC**

---

There are many users and I use the [functional-red-black-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/functional-red-black-tree) data structure to improve performance.
In this data structure, each item has a key and a value.
The constructor of this tree takes a comparator function -like array sort comparator- with two parameters, each of which are keys, as a parameter.

I have defined the **user** as follows:

```
class Key {
    constructor(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime) {
        this.ipv4 = ipv4;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.score = score;
        this.loginTime = loginTime;
    }
}

class OnlineUser {

    constructor(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime, name, avatar, bio, gender) {
        this.key = new Key(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime);
        this.name = name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
module.exports = { OnlineUser, Key };
```

And I defined the **tree** with the comparator function like this:

```
const createTree = require('functional-red-black-tree');

var tree = createTree((userAKey, userBKey) => {
    if (userAKey.ipv4 == userBKey.ipv4) return 0;
    if (userAKey.rank < userBKey.rank) return 1;
    if (userAKey.rank > userBKey.rank) return -1;
    if (userAKey.score < userBKey.score) return 1;
    if (userAKey.score > userBKey.score) return -1;
    if (userAKey.loginTime < userBKey.loginTime) return -1;
    if (userAKey.loginTime > userBKey.loginTime) return 1;
});
```

And to add user:

```
tree = tree.insert(user.key, user);
```

**Problem:**
All users are added in the correct order. But to access or delete or... users are often returned the `undefined`:

```
const OnlineUser = require('./model/OnlineUser').OnlineUser;
const Key = require('./model/OnlineUser').Key;

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let user = new OnlineUser(i, rand(), rand(), rand(), '', '', '', 1);
    tree = tree.insert(user.key, user);
}
console.log(tree.get(new Key(10, 0, 0, 0)));

function rand() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
```

I think this problem is because the comparator function uses different values for comparison and equality.

The solution that seems to me is to hash all the keys and turn it into a key that is hashed as follows:

```
function hash(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime){
    let hashCode;
    //How to implement?
    return hashCode;
}
```

- If the **ipv4** is equal to others, the hash values will be the same regardless of the other keys.
- If the **ipv4** is not equal and the **rank** is greater than the others, the hash value will be greater than the others (except for the previous conditions) regardless of the other keys.
- If the **ipv4** is not equal and the **rank** is equal to others and the **score** is greater than the others, the hash value will be
  greater than the others (except for the previous conditions) regardless of the other keys.
- If the **ipv4** is not equal and the **rank** is equal to others and the **score** is equal to others and the **login time** is less than others, the hash value will be
  greater than the others (except for the previous conditions) regardless of the other keys.

Comment: *"But to access or delete or... users are often returned the undefined."*: Can you add the code that reproduces this `undefined` behaviour?

Comment: I added the code and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rand` example, it is normal that the key (10, 0, 0, 0) will not match, even though ipv4=10 is somewhere in the tree. This is because that node will be more like (10, 66, 35, 19)... which will not be encountered, as the *ordering* of the tree is mainly  based on rank, not on ipv4. The decision to where to drill down in the tree will be based on rank (0), moving to the left side of the tree, while the node you intend to find may be at the right (higher rank 66).

What you can do is to accompany the tree with a `Map`, which will map an ipv4 value with an existing `Key` instance. So every time you insert in the tree, also add the corresponding mapping in that Map. And every time you want to find or want to delete, first retrieve the `Key` instance from that Map by the ipv4 value you have, and pass that `Key` instance to the tree's `get` or `remove` method.

Here is a wrapper class that makes this combination. Extend it with any other method you want to include:

```
const createTree = require('functional-red-black-tree');

class Key {
    constructor(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime) {
        this.ipv4 = ipv4;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.score = score;
        this.loginTime = loginTime;
    }
}

class OnlineUser {
    constructor(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime, name, avatar, bio, gender) {
        this.key = new Key(ipv4, rank, score, loginTime);
        this.name = name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(comparator) {
        this.tree = createTree(comparator);
        this.map = new Map;
    }
    insert(user) {
        this.tree = this.tree.insert(user.key, user);
        this.map.set(user.key.ipv4, user.key);
    }
    get(ipv4) {
        let key = this.map.get(ipv4);
        if (key) return this.tree.get(key);
    }
    remove(ipv4) {
        let key = this.map.get(ipv4);
        if (key) return tree.remove(key);
    }
}

let tree = new Tree((userAKey, userBKey) =>
    userBKey.rank - userAKey.rank ||
    userBKey.score - userAKey.score ||
    userBKey.loginTime - userAKey.loginTime
);

// Insert  some data:
let userA = new OnlineUser("1.1.1.1", 0, 3000, 1631966424070, "userA");
let userB = new OnlineUser("2.2.2.2", 1, 2000, 1631966424080, "userB");
let userC = new OnlineUser("3.3.3.3", 1, 1000, 1631966424090, "userC");
let userD = new OnlineUser("4.4.4.4", 0, 3000, 1631966424100, "userD");

for (let user of [userA, userB, userC, userD]) {
    tree.insert(user);
}

// Make use of the redblack `forEach`:
tree.tree.forEach((key, value) => console.log(value.name))
// Use our own `get` method:
console.log(tree.get("3.3.3.3")); // userC
```

Comment: Is there a library (with insert O(log n)) for this data structure that combines tree and map?

Comment: Just make a wrapper yourself? It is quite simple.

Comment: I added a little implementation to my answer. Extend as needed.

Comment: Great, your solution works.

Comment: How much memory is used with this data structure? Does adding a map double that amount?

Comment: I don't know how much memory the red black implementation uses, but the *values* in the Map are not new `Key` instances, but already existing ones. So they just occupy a reference. The keys of the Map are strings, and some JavaScript engines will optimise so that the same string (ipv4) is not stored twice. Then there is the Map implementation for hashing. The memory usage is certainly not twice as much, but less.

Comment: You could also give up on the redblack library you use, and go for one that provides a sorted set interface. For instance [collections.js](https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-map)